# Running dbt tests as a pre-hook, prior to running a model

Tags: dbt

I want to prevent the scenario where my model runs, even though any number of source tables are (erroneously) empty. The phrase coming to mind is a "pre-hook," although I'm not sure that's the right terminology.

Ideally I'd run `dbt run --select MY_MODEL` and as a part of that, these tests for non-emptiness in the source tables would run. However, I'm not sure dbt works like that. Currently I'm thinking I'll have to apply these tests to the sources and run those tests (according to [this document](https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/tests/testing-sources)), prior to executing `dbt run`.

Is there a more direct way of having `dbt run` fail if any of these sources are empty?

Answer (score -1):

Personally the way I'd go about this would be to define your `my_source.yml`
to have `not_null` tests on every column using something like [this docs example](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/source-properties#example)

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: jaffle_shop
    database: raw
    schema: public
    loader: emr # informational only (free text)
    loaded_at_field: _loaded_at # configure for all sources

    tables:
      - name: orders
        identifier: Orders_
        loaded_at_field: updated_at # override source defaults
        columns:
          - name: id
            tests:
              - not_null

          - name: price_in_usd
            tests:
              - not_null
```

And then in your run / build, use the following order of operations:

`dbt test --select source:*`

`dbt build`

In this circumstance, I'd highly recommend making your own variation on the `generate_source` macro from [dbt-codegen](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-codegen) which automatically defines your sources with columns & not_null tests included.